# Admin And User Permission In PHP

Tags: php

So i am making my own website and also im new in php code im just beginning with it i have a problem how do i disable user with a role as a "User" and cannot visit "Admin" pages only with "Admin" role can visit and use it. What will be my PHP code with this problem? i saw some code but i really having problem understanding it because im just new in PHP code.

here is my code that i use in my problem

**server.php**

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { // user found
            // check if user is admin or user
            $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
            if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'admin') {

                $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
                header('location: admin/home.php');       
            }else{
                $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";

                header('location: index.php');
            }
```

but user role is still able to access admin/home.php

also in admin/home.php i have this code

**home.php**

```
if (!isLoggedIn()) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: ../errors-404.html');
}
```

**this is the function of isLoggedIn**

```
function isLoggedIn()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: both user types are login, you need to check for the user_type (admin) and base on that allow or deny access.

Comment: @Vidal do you have any tutorial for it?

Comment: @MikeeAshklanov  I have written some logic in my answer, let me know if you still have issues or need any explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add user type checking in your `isLoggedIn()`-function:

```
function isLoggedIn($type = null)
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        // We got no session at all. Not logged in.
        return false;
    }

    $currentType = $_SESSION['user']['user_type'] ?? null;

    if ($type && $type != $currentType) {
        // We got a type passed to the function, but the session type
        // doesn't match
        return false;
    }

    // Either we got no type or the type matched.
    return true;
}
```

Now you can use it for checking if a user is logged in at all (by omitting the argument) or if the user has a specific role (by passing the role to the function):

To check if a user is logged in at all:

```
// In the top of the page you want to protect
if (!isLoggedIn()) {
    // Not logged in at all
    header('location: foo.php');
    exit;
}
```

To check if a user is logged in with a specific role:

```
// In the top of the page you want to protect
if (!isLoggedIn('admin')) {
    // Not logged in as an admin
    header('location: bar.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: where should i put `isLoggedIn('admin')` and `isLoggedIn();` ?

Comment: If you only need to check if a user is logged in (no matter the role), do: `if (!isLoggedIn()) { ... }` and if you need to check if the user has a specific role, you just do: `if (!isLoggedIn('admin')) { ... }`. I would recommend having this in the top of the pages you want to protect.

Comment: Wow! it actually works thanks for the helped! how do i close this thread?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are just checking if the `$_SESSION['user']` is set or not and it's set in both cases.

Check it as:

```
function isAdmin()
{
  //this checks is user is logged in and type == "admin" 
 return (isset($_SESSION['user']) &&   isset($_SESSION['user_type']) && ($_SESSION['user_type']=="admin")  ); 

}
```

Conceptually there should be another function like this

```
function validateLogin(){

   if(isLoggedIn()){
     if(isAdmin()){
       //redirect to admin page
      } 
      else{
              //redirect to user page
      } 
   }
   else{
      // invalid login
   } 
}
```

And on the top of your `.php` files for admin, use the same function to validate if the user has access to that particular page or not.

Comment: do i need to put validatelogin in each admin pages?

Comment: definitely, you need this isadmin function to be called above all. you do not want others users to access admin pages

Comment: do i just add the function isadmin below my isLoggedIn?

Comment: i see something wrong with my question i re edit it im very sorry i re edit the code in home.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the below function on admin page.

```
function isLoggedIn()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'admin') {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your redirection logic to error page in your question.

Comment: i see something wrong with my question i re edit it im very sorry i re edit the code in home.php

Comment: Can i see the array structure of your session, by using `print_r` in `isLoggedIn` function.